# How to fetch a url asynchronously with pyppeteer(One browser many tabs)

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, pyppeteer

I want my script to

1. Open say 3 tabs
2. Asynchronously fetch a url(same for each tab)
3. Save the response
4. Sleep for 4 seconds
5. Parse through the response with regex(I tried BeautifulSoup but its too slow) and return a token
6. Loop through several times within the 3 tabs

My problem is with 2. I have an example script but it synchronously fetches the url. I would like to make it asynchronous.

```
from pyppeteer import launch

urls = ['https://www.example.com']


async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    for url in urls:
        page1 = await browser.newPage()
        page2 = await browser.newPage()
        page3 = await browser.newPage()

        await page1.goto(url)
        await page2.goto(url)
        await page3.goto(url)

        title1= await page1.title()
        title2= await page2.title()
        title3= await page3.title()

        print(title1)
        print(title2)
        print(title3)

    #await browser.close()


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Also, as you can see, the code is not so concise. How do I go about making it asynchronous?

Also if it helps, I have other pyppeteer scripts which don't fit my need just in case it would be easier to convert those

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

url = 'http://www.example.com'
browser = None

async def fetchUrl(url):
    # Define browser as a global variable to ensure that the browser window is only created once in the entire process
    global browser
    if browser is None:
        browser = await launch(headless=False)

    page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto(url)
    #await asyncio.wait([page.waitForNavigation()])
    #str = await page.content()
    #print(str)

 # Execute this function multiple times for testing
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(fetchUrl(url))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(fetchUrl(url))
```

The script is asynchronous but it executes one event loop at a time so its as good as synchronous.

```
# cat test.py
import asyncio
import time
from pyppeteer import launch

WEBSITE_LIST = [
    'http://envato.com',
    'http://amazon.co.uk',
    'http://example.com',
]

start = time.time()

async def fetch(url):
    browser = await launch(headless=False, args=['--no-sandbox'])
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(f'{url}', {'waitUntil': 'load'})
    print(f'{url}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await page.close()
    #await browser.close()

async def run():
    tasks = []

    for url in WEBSITE_LIST:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url))
        tasks.append(task)

    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
loop.run_until_complete(future)

print(f'It took {time.time()-start} seconds.')
```

The script is asynchronous but it launches a separate browser for each url which ends up taking too many resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will open each URL in a separate tab:

```
import asyncio
import traceback

from pyppeteer import launch

URLS = [
    "http://envato.com",
    "http://amazon.co.uk",
    "http://example.com",
]


async def fetch(browser, url):
    page = await browser.newPage()

    try:
        await page.goto(f"{url}", {"waitUntil": "load"})
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    else:
        html = await page.content()
        return (url, html)
    finally:
        await page.close()


async def main():
    tasks = []
    browser = await launch(headless=True, args=["--no-sandbox"])

    for url in URLS:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch(browser, url)))

    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        url, html = await coro
        print(f"{url}: ({len(html)})")

    await browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank you @HTF. Is there a way I can access the nth url using the code? Suppose I wanted to access the 5th tab after all the urls are open.

Comment: You can use [Browser.pages](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#pyppeteer.browser.Browser.pages) to get all pages/tabs.

Comment: I ask because page.type doesn't seem to work with the code unless its in headless mode. If in non-headless mode only the tab in focus works. The other tabs only work when you manually navigate to them.

Comment: It works even for typing though its not fully asynchronous(for typing) but I'll use it as is. I launched 50 tabs with it and used tasks and found that at any one time, it was the last task that was being executed.